# Golang mongodb field level encryption

Tags: mongodb, go, encryption

I am trying to encrypt certain fields in mongodb using mgo and Golang. Since mongodb does not support field level encryption , I was thinking of encrypting and decrypting the data while marshalling the data and unmarshalling the data.

For example, in the struct below I want to encrypt Name and Gender

if my struct as like this

```
type User struct {
UserID      string `json:"userID,omitempty" bson:"userID,omitempty"`
UserName    string `json:"userName,omitempty" bson:"userName,omitempty"`
UserAge   string `json:"userAge,omitempty" bson:"userAge,omitempty"`
UserGender string `json:"userGender,omitempty" bson:"userGender,omitempty"`
}
```

One way to solve this is after marshalling the data, encrypt the data before saving in the db, and a similar approach for sending the data back to the UI.  Is there an event that I can listen to before the marshalling and unmarshalling of data? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The "event" is the actual call to your `GetBSON()` and `SetBSON()` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since mongodb does not support field level encryption

MongoDB v4.2 now supports [Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-client-side-encryption/), see also [Field Level Encryption is GA](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/field-level-encryption-is-ga). There are two supported types:

- [Manual Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-explicit-client-side-encryption/)

  Applications must modify any code associated with constructing read and write operations to include encryption/decryption logic via the driver encryption library. Applications are responsible for selecting the appropriate data encryption key for encryption/decryption on a per-operation basis.
- [Automatic Client-Side Field Level Encryption](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-automatic-client-side-encryption/) (available only on [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas), or [MongoDB Enterprise Advanced](https://www.mongodb.com/products/mongodb-enterprise-advanced))

  Applications do not have to modify code associated with the read/write operation.

Looking at your requirements, it seems that you'd want the `automatic` encryption/decryption. You can try this with Free-Tier Atlas cluster see: [Getting Started with Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/getting-started/).

> encrypt certain fields in mongodb using mgo and Golang

Unfortunately this is not available on [mgo](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo), but on [mongo-go-driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) v1.2+. You can see some examples on [MongoDB Go driver: Client Side Encryption](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#hdr-Client_Side_Encryption). An example to create a `MongoClient` configured with auto encryption is:

```
func createEncryptedClient() *mongo.Client {
        // create a client with auto encryption
        schemaMap := map[string]interface{}{
                "foo.bar": readJSONFile("collection_schema.json"),
        }
        autoEncOpts := options.AutoEncryption().
                SetKeyVaultNamespace("keyvault.__datakeys").
                SetKmsProviders(kmsProviders).
                SetSchemaMap(schemaMap)

        clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetAutoEncryptionOptions(autoEncOpts)
        autoEncryptionClient, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Connect error for client with automatic encryption: %v", err)
        }
        return autoEncryptionClient
}
```

See also [github.com/mongodb-labs/field-level-encryption-sandbox](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/field-level-encryption-sandbox/tree/master/go)